# How to use libint with Python

Tags: quantum-chemistry, python, hartree-fock

I am trying to write a basic [Hartree-Fock code](https://github.com/HemanthHaridas/plank.py) to compute orbital energies and total energy of a molecule at almost all basis sets. I wrote the integral code in Cython/Python and is very slow. I would like to use libint to compute the integrals. However, I am unable to find references to use the libint library in python. Any pointers to use libint library in python would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a alternative runtime, like PyPy? If your integral code is pure python it should be able to run on pypy. Depending on the speedup you need, it may suffice. From https://speed.pypy.org/ : "The geometric average of all benchmarks is 0.21 or 4.8 times faster than cpython".

Comment: @ksousa, my code is a mixture of Cython and Python, with the computationally heavy sections implemented in Cython. However, I am now trying to rework that code to include optimized libraries wherever possible. That's why I am interested in getting libint to work with Python.

Comment: Well, there's a [test_hf.py](https://github.com/evaleev/libint/blob/master/python/tests/test_hf.py) script that's part of the `libint` tests - it looks like a complete script for water.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PyQuante](https://pyquante.sourceforge.net/) is one of the first quantum chemistry codes written in Python, and it has been around for a long time. There is a binding to Ed Valeev's libint version 1 in PyQuante, see [clibint.c](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyquante/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Src/lib/clibint.c) and [clibint.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyquante/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Src/lib/clibint.h); I am sure these will be as much help to you as they were for me a decade ago when I wrote my own interface to libint.

Comment: Thank you @SusiLehtola.

Answer (score 4):

#### Some background:

The following answer by [Anycorn](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/6472/anycorn) was "accepted" by the OP:

> "I wrote python bindings for libint. Did you look in python/tests? there are two tests, including sample hf program"

but it was deleted due to being "[very low quality](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15224/202425)".

Geoff's [comment](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-to-use-libint-with-python#comment21544_10145) was even better, as it gave the exact URL to a complete script, rather than just suggesting for the OP to look in a folder where they may or may not find what they need.

#### Conclusion:

Using libint with Python has been demonstrated for the $\ce{H2O}$ molecule in [this complete script](https://github.com/evaleev/libint/blob/master/python/tests/test_hf.py).

Comment: @GeoffHutchison you might have an opinion on [this Meta post](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/5)!